# Problema para atualizar registro do banco com ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Boa noite, 
Estou tentando atualizar dados do banco via ajax, só que não está funcionando,tenho dois text area, e atualizo ele com update. Antes de tentar sem o ajax, estava funcionando perfeitamente, só agora que não quer pegar mais... não consigo mais identificar o erro, podem me ajudar?

Meu form e ajax:

```
            <form method="POST" id="formulario_mensagem">

                <input type="text" name="msg_id" id="msg_id" value="<?php echo $row['msg_id'];  ?>">


                <textarea type="text" name="msg_original" id="msg_original" rows="5">"<?php $st=$row['msg_text']; echo 
                str_replace('+', '<br />', $st);?>"</textarea>

                <textarea type="text" name="msg_nova" id="msg_nova" rows="5" placeholder="Digite a Resposta Aqui"></textarea>

                <button type="submit" onclick="inserir_registo()">Reenviar</button>
            </form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function inserir_registo()
{
    //dados a enviar, vai buscar os valores dos campos que queremos enviar para a BD
    var dadosajax = {
        'msg_id' : $("#msg_id").val(),
        'msg_original' : $("#msg_original").val(),
        'msg_nova' : $("#msg_nova").val()
    };
     pageurl = 'fetch_mensagem.php';
    //para consultar mais opcoes possiveis numa chamada ajax
    //http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    $.ajax({

        //url da pagina
        url:pageurl,
        //parametros a passar
        data: dadosajax,
        //tipo: POST ou GET
        type: 'POST',
        //cache
        cache: false,
        //se ocorrer um erro na chamada ajax, retorna este alerta
        //possiveis erros: pagina nao existe, erro de codigo na pagina, falha de comunicacao/internet, etc etc etc
        error: function(){
            alert('Erro: Ao Enviar Mensagem!');
        },
        //retorna o resultado da pagina para onde enviamos os dados
        success: function(result)
        { 
            //se foi inserido com sucesso
            if($.trim(result) == '1')
            {
                alert("Mensagem enviada com sucesso!");
            }
            //se foi um erro
            else
            {
                alert("Ocorreu um erro ao enviar mensagem!");
            }

        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Meu fetch_mensagem.php:

```
<?php
 include "verifica_sessao.php";
  include "config.php";

      date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

      $data=date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
      $id = $_POST['msg_id'];
      $texto = $_POST['msg_original'];
      $novo = $_POST['msg_nova'];

//Aqui arrumo o texto e faço o update
      $saida = '';
      $saida .= $id;
      $saida .= '.';
      $saida .= '\n \n';
      $saida .= $texto;
      $saida .= '.';
      $saida .= '\n \n';
      $saida .= $novo;

      $result = $db->prepare("UPDATE mensagens SET msg_text='$saida' WHERE msg_id='$id' AND msg_status=0");
      $result->execute();
       while($row = $result->fetch()){
        if( $result->fetch()){ 
             echo '1';             
                  }
                  else{
                     echo '0'; 
                     }
                }
?>
```

Antes estava utilizando o action e pegava normal, só que agora simplesmente parou...quem puder me ajudar agradeço..

Comment: vc alterou algo em seu arquivo fetch_mensagem.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrija a sua chamada com ajax assim, teste e me retorna se está ok. Acredito que já vai resolver o seu problema:

Mude o seu botão: `<button type="submit" onclick="inserir_registo()">Reenviar</button>`
para: `<button type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar" id="enviar">Reenviar</button>`

Ao invés de `onClick()` vamos chamar o ajax no `submit` do form. Ok?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#formulario_mensagem').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#enviar').val() == 'Enviando...'){
        return(false);
    }

    $.ajax({
       url: 'fetch_mensagem.php',
       type: 'post',
       dataType: 'html',
       data: {
           'msg_id' : $("#msg_id").val(),
           'msg_original' : $("#msg_original").val(),
           'msg_nova' : $("#msg_nova").val()
       }
    }).done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    });

});
</script>
```

Eu deixei `alert(data);` assim vai te retornar o tiver na sua página. Qualquer coisa só me falar.

Comment: Muito obrigado Leandro funcionou perfeitamente!